# Display previous month data in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How do I filter previous month data from Google big query (ex: Jan 1st - Jan 31)

```
select count(distinct hits.customDimensions.value,20000000) as TotalUniqueUsers, 
       count(distinct IF(visitnumber=1, hits.customDimensions.value, NULL),20000000) as TotalNewUsers
from TABLE_DATE_RANGE([90461009.ga_sessions_],
                      DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -2, 'MONTH'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'MONTH')
                     )
where hits.customDimensions.index=4
```

I am trying something like the above query. Could somebody help please

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT hits.customDimensions.value,20000000) AS TotalUniqueUsers, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(visitnumber=1, hits.customDimensions.value, NULL),20000000) AS TotalNewUsers
FROM TABLE_QUERY([90461009],
  "REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, 'ga_sessions_' + REPLACE(LEFT(STRING(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'MONTH')), 7), '-', ''))")
WHERE hits.customDimensions.index=4
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mikhail ! That helped :)